# How does .index method of str work in python?

Tags: python, string, sorting

**How does this code work?**

```
values = ['1', '3', '9', '6', '7']  # just an example of what comes in
index = "123456789"["8" in values:].index  # everything except this line is understandable
print(sorted(values, key=index))
```

this kind of code looks very strange to me so i don't understand how it works.

```
str[str in list:].index
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is needlessly complicated code. Either someone did something incorrectly, or they're trying to be clever. Here's what that line means:

```
index = "123456789"["8" in values:].index
```

Start with the `"8" in values`. This evaluates to `False`, because `"8"` is not in the `values` list. This is the same as:

```
index = "123456789"[False:].index
```

which, because `False` evaluates to `0`, is just the same as:

```
index = "123456789"[0:].index
```

and because `[0:]` refers to the entire string, this:

```
index = "123456789".index
```

sets the variable `index` to point to the `.index()` method of the string `"123456789"`. This is then used as the key to `sorted()` which has the effect of sorting `values` based on the index of each value in the `"123456789"` string.

In the end, this is the same as:

```
print(sorted(values))
```

Answer (score 1):

`index = "123456789"["8" in values:].index  # everything except this line is understandable`

There are a couple things happening on that line and we can split it into multiple lines to understand what is happening:

```py
values = ['1', '3', '9', '6', '7']  # just an example of what comes in
boolean = ("8" in values)
numbers = "123456789"[boolean:]
index = numbers.index  # everything except this line is understandable
print(sorted(values, key=index))
```

Let's start with `"8" in values` this produces a boolean output which is `False` because there is no `8` in the `values` list.

Now we have `"123456789"[False:]` In python strings can be accessed like an array with [ ] brackets.

Let's take a closer look at that colon because that may look confusing as well. The colon is also used in python for [slicing](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/colon-in-python) and when its placed on the right side of an index, it specifies everything after that index including the index.

But hang on, False isn't a number yet. Right, python converts False to 0 so as a final result we have `"123456789"[0:]`. So this complicated code does nothing for us because it just returns the entire string `"123456789"`.

Now we are at `index = numbers.index` , which is really `index = "123456789".index`.
This stores the index method of the string `"123456789"`.

This is used in the sorted method.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions states "The value of the key parameter should be a function (or other callable) that takes a single argument and returns a key to use for sorting purposes."

This will call "123456789".index(number) for every number in values, and use the returned index to provide the sorting like this:

Let's recap `values = ['1', '3', '9', '6', '7']` and `"123456789"`

```
"123456789".index('1') # Gives 0 (because the index of '1' in `"123456789"` is 0)  
"123456789".index('3') # Gives 2 (because the index of '3' in `"123456789"` is 2)  
"123456789".index('9') # Gives 8  
"123456789".index('6') # Gives 5  
"123456789".index('7') # Gives 6
```

Now it uses these numbers and sorts them from least to greatest (0,2,5,6,8) and presents the values from `values = ['1', '3', '9', '6', '7']` in that order. (0 corresponded to '1' so that goes first, 2 corresponded to '3', 5 corresponded to '6' and so on.)

#### Conclusion

```
values = ['1', '3', '9', '6', '7']  # just an example of what comes in
index = "123456789"["8" in values:].index  # everything except this line is understandable
print(sorted(values, key=index))
```

This code used a very complicated way to sort the list of numerical strings.
Below is a more clear way of doing it that will work for lists that have numbers that exceed 1-9.

Recommended (works for all integers):

```
values = ['1', '3', '9', '6', '7']  # just an example of what comes in
print(sorted(values, key=int))
```

How does it work? The `int` function first converts each element in values to an integer as provided as a `key` function to `sorted`. When python receives numbers to sort it will automatically sort them from least to greatest.